# Avoiding range of a bivariate integer function or diophantine function

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

I'm trying to find a function or sequence (of integers) which avoids all the range values of the following integer function where $x,y \in \{0,1,2,...\}$ and $f(x,y)=5+23*x+7*y+30*x*y$. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/217492/avoiding-the-range-of-a-bivariate-function-or-diophantine-function

Answer (score 1):

$(1,1,1,\cdots)$ avoids the range, as requested.

Comment: Clarifying further, I need an infinite, increasing, integer sequence which avoids the range of the function.

Comment: @Anoneemouse: **Why** do you need one?

Comment: This is all based out of a possible research idea but I'm only just starting my second year of grad school and don't have familiarity with this sort of function. I've also tried turning it into a bivariate polynomial function by letting $x=(a+b)$ and $y=(a-b)$ to get thhe xy apart. This function is actually a piece of a larger function and I thought if I can avoid the range on this one maybe I can figure out how to do the same for a larger function

Comment: @Anoneemouse: Then I'm afraid I don't have any idea that seems to work.